# Paperclip image doesn't show in Action Mailer email

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, actionmailer

I'm writing a very simple email template that send an HTML email with an embedded image. The image is stored in AWS S3 using Paperclip gem:

```
<%= image_tag @press_release.image.try(:attachment).try(:url, :preview), alt: 'zimplePR', style: 'width: 85%; max-height: 200px; object-fit: cover;' %>
```

In production, that `image_tag` helper works as a charm in my web view, but for some reason there is not displayed in my emails sent.

I read somewhere that maybe it is because the full attachment url of Paperclip is something like `//s3.amazonaws.com/...` and prepending 'http:' should work, but that only works in Gmail, but not in Apple email for example.

Is there a way to embed the image in an ActionMailer template using Paperclip and beign displayed in all email clients?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the cause of that error was because I wasn't specified the :http protocol of the attachment:

```
Class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :styles => {
                      :thumb   => ['80x80>', :png],
                      :preview => ['600x600>', :png]
                    },
                    :convert_options =>{
                      :thumb   => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
                      :preview => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
                    },
                    :default_url => 'images/missing_:style.png',
                    :s3_protocol => :https,
                    :s3_credentials => {
                      :bucket => Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:s3_bucket_production]
                    }
end
```